# How is it possible that my iPhone is using data when on airplane mode?

Tags: data, airplane-mode

All our phones are using data during the night when we are asleep.  I thought that apps were only supposed to update on WIFI.  But my phone is always on airplane mode at night unless I forget, so last night I put in on airplane mode, took a screenshot as evidence, and sure enough, a tiny bit of data was used at 6:00am this morning before I got up.  How is that possible?

Comment: that would not be possible, since as you know the WiFi and cellular radio are off in Airplane mode.

Comment: How do you know that data was used? Maybe it is only a statistics thing...

Comment: It is possible to have WiFi on while in Airplane mode.  Be sure to check in settings that WiFi is also turned off on your device.  If so, then you have a good one for the folks at the Apple Genius bar.

Comment: WIFI was also off.

Comment: I know data was used because it is on the AT&T website.  Iv

Comment: I have been checking data on the AT&T website every day trying to figure out why we have so much unexplained unintentionally used data.  That's when I found out that all the phones are using data at 6:00am, some at 2 or 3 am.  That's why we did the test last night watching each other turn on airplane mode so we could check this morning and see if they used data.

Comment: So I guess I get to talk to the genius bar first, then AT&T

Comment: Data usage reporting on the AT&T website can be delayed, it's not reported instantly.  They specifically state that data usage is reported every 3 hours, but may take up to 72 hours for all usage to be collected.

Comment: Was the data wifi or cell? A further experiment is to disable the wifi router at night as well, and see if the iPhone transmits less data. Depending where you live (if in the US) local law enforcement, federal alphabet agencies & the like may be [over-flying your neighborhood](http://bit.ly/2oKzFds) and causing your phone to activate.

Answer (score 1):

@Tyson's comment provides some insight based on your checking the data usage with your carrier, AT&T.

The time that is posted by AT&T is the time that they added the usage to your account, not necessarily the time that the usage was done.

As an experiment, if you can spare one of your iPhones that long, is to set it in Airplane mode for a day or two and see what AT&T reports.  [This thread](https://forums.att.com/t5/Wireless-2014-Archive/Longer-than-usual-delay-in-usage-reporting/td-p/3889727) on the AT&T forum explains some of the fine print.

[image: AT&T terms]

Comment: Turning them off would be an interesting test too.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 iPhones on my desk and I often switch both of phone into flight mode with wifi off after 9:00 pm and turn off the router's wifi at the same time, and there is a radio electromagnetic field meter on the same desk. And some days ago, the meter detected some electromagnetic field, as strong as wifi on the phone is on and near to the meter. SO I started to be curious since then.  The sign last for around 10 seconds. I think even when iPhone is flight mode with wifi off, there maybe be some system mechanism inside iPhone to detect wifi around or the iPhone itself was trying to send some data out. And maybe my iPhone was hacked.:)